# How I Convert a string representation of a nested list into a nested list?

Tags: python, string, list, nested

I have a string representing a nested list:
`string = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

And a would like to convert it to a list:
`list =  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`

I've tried using `string.split("]'[").split(', ')` but it still returning `[ ['1,2,3],[4,5,6'] ]`

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You could do something like `lst = eval(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a string like `string = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"` and you want to convert it to a list object like `lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`, you could simply use the eval method:
`lst = eval(string)`

Comment: Thank you sir! Didn't knew eval() could be used for that :D it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have problem using external library, You can use [`pyyaml`](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to achieve that:

```py
>>> from yaml import CLoader as Loader, CDumper as Dumper
>>> import yaml
>>> string = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
>>> yaml.load(string, Loader=Loader)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need `eval()` builtin. Starting from python 3.9, better use `ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`, it more safer:

```
from ast import literal_eval

a_str = '[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]'
b_list = eval(a_str)
print(b_list)
# from python 3.9 better to use this, instead of eval():
c_list = literal_eval(a_str)
print(c_list)
```

Read:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Answer (score 0):

`ast.literal_eval(string)` is what you're looking for. In this case that would end up looking like

```py
from ast import literal_eval

string = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
list = literal_eval(string)
print(list)
```

Using `eval` from python is considered dangerous, especially if the input for it is done outside of code. This is a safe alternative that still does what you're looking for.

There's a couple of issues with your first approach (ignore this part if you don't care to be lectured). First, it seems like your variable `string` is actually already a list instead of a string. I'll be assuming this is a typo and you meant `string = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"` instead.

`str.split(sep)` takes a string that will be used as the separator, so `str.split("]'[")` will try to split on the exact string `"]'["` where it seems you're expecting it to split on any single one of those characters. The result is that you are given a list of a single string, `["[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"]`.